# which chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ of $z=f(\frac{x}{y})$

Thoughts

If I write $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$, then $z=f(g(x,y))$. Which Chain Rule do I use now?

help please

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$z=f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=f'\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)\frac{1}{y}$$ and

$$z=f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=f'\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)\frac{-x}{y^2}.$$

First, you derive $f$ (with derivative $f'$) and then you get the derivative of $\frac{x}{y}$ with respect to $x$ or $y.$ The chain rule says that $f_x$ or $f_y$ is the product of the derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

As a point of technicality, there is only one Chain Rule so it doesn't make sense to say "which" Chain Rule. Anyway, I think the substitution $g(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$ is unnecessary. Let's calculate $\frac{\partial z }{\partial y}$ first to see that. The Chain Rule tells us that $$\frac{\partial z }{\partial y} = \left[f\left( \frac{x}{y}\right)\right]' \\ = f'\left( \frac{x}{y}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{x}{y} \right)' \\ = f'\left( \frac{x}{y}\right) \cdot \frac{-x}{y^2}$$

Can you repeat a similar process to find $\frac{\partial z }{\partial x}$?